# Cloud Dataflow job reading from one Bigquery project and writing to another BigQuery project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, service-accounts

I'm implementing a Cloud Dataflow job on GCP that needs to deal with 2 GCP projects.
Both input and output are Bigquery partitionned tables.
The issue I'm going through now is that I must read data from a project A and write it into a project B.

I havent seen anything related to cross project service accounts and I can't give Dataflow two different credential key either which is a bit annoying ?
I don't know if someone else went through that kind of architecture or how you dealt with it.

Comment: Could you add more specifics to your question? 
Is using Dataflow a hard requirement or more a preference/current solution? 
What are you doing with the 2 BigQuery tables? Reading them into Dataflow's PCols or actually doing something else?
From the sound of it, you might be using some templatized Dataflow job, if so, which one?

Comment: If the answers do not work for you, please comment here, and I'll try to help you figure this out. I believe Brent's answer should do the trick.

Comment: So: yes Dataflow is a hard architecture requirement like having 2 BigQuery datasets in separate environment: these are like my architecture constraints.
So I read the data from tables in dataset A then apply custom transformations for ML model preparation and then push this to dataset B, I'm not using templatized jobs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this with the following steps:

1. Create a dedicated service account in the project running the Dataflow job.
2. Grant the service account the **Dataflow Worker** and **BigQuery Job User** roles.  The service account might need additional roles based on the full resource needs of the Dataflow job.
3. In Project A, grant the service account the **BigQuery Data Viewer** role to either the entire project or to specific datasets.
4. In Project B, grant the service account the **BigQuery Data Editor** role to either the entire project or to specific datasets.
5. When you start the Dataflow job, override the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#controller_service_account) pipeline option supplying the new service account.

Comment: So your answer looks like what I need, followed these steps but while testing, 
I get an error due to the project option I need to supply : I give projectA option and try to write to projectB  like :
google_cloud_options.project = "projectA"
...
    data | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(bigquery.TableReference(
        projectId="projectB",
        datasetId="test",
        tableId='output_test_table')
        ...
    )
By doing so, I can't write to projectB and it tries writing in projectA which following error:
Project A: User does not have bigquery.datasets.create permission in A.

Comment: How are you writing to BigQuery?   If you are using BigQueryIO, supply the correct project id constructing the transform.  If you are using a BigQuery client, include the correct project id in any SQL.

Comment: I made it work with a dedicated service account that had BigQuery Admin rights though

Comment: If you still want to limit the roles so Admin role isn't need, you might be able to the BigQuery audit logs.  Those log entries have a section that lists the account and requested permission for BigQuery operations.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. you need to give required permission/access to your service account from both the project.

So you need only service account which has required access/permission in both the project

Hope it helps.