Cloud Dataflow to read data from one Bigquery project and writing to another BigQuery project
I'm implementing a Cloud Dataflow job on GCP that needs to deal with 2 GCP projects. Both input and output are Bigquery tables. The issue I'm going through now is that I must read data from a project A and write it into a project B.
insert into project A
select from Project B
How to do this?
cross-project data loading using dataflow

I think this might have already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61685069/cloud-dataflow-job-reading-from-one-bigquery-project-and-writing-to-another-bigq?rq=2
